# Inline edit grid magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

How to create Inline Edit in grid? I need controller file or only do this in  view ui_component?

I created this in ui_component but not working

```
<item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
<item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_columns_editor</item>
    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: You need a controller to save the values you change in inline-grid.

Comment: But I can not change anything in my grid

Answer (score 0):

You can take the reference from CMS module of core Magneto. This is the reference link for that https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_listing.xml

Like showing in this file you need to add editorConfig to configure inline edit and you also need to create controller.

```
<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">cms_block_listing.cms_block_listing.cms_block_columns.ids</item>
    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">block_id</item>
    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="cms/block/inlineEdit"/>
        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Ui_component.xml place this code make inline edit work.

```
<settings>           
        <editorConfig>
            <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="route/controllerfolder/controller"/>
                <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </param>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">primary_field</param>
            <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
            <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_columns.ids</param>
        </editorConfig>
        <childDefaults>
            <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_index.test_mytesting_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </childDefaults>
    </settings>
```

To show a column in Inline-edit, add below code

```
 <column name="your_field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Field Label</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Next you need to create a controller,**route/controllerfolder/controller**.

```
Vendor/Module/Controller/Area(frontend(or)Adminhtml)/controllerfolder/controller

<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\controllerfolder;

class controller extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

protected $jsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
    $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $error = false;
    $messages = [];

    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
        $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
        if (!count($postItems)) {
            $messages[] = __('Please correct the data sent.');
            $error = true;
        } else {
            foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $entityId) {
                /** load your model to update the data */
                $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\YourModel')->load($entityId);
                try {
                    $model->setData(array_merge($model->getData(), $postItems[$entityId]));
                    $model->save();
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $messages[] = "[Error:]  {$e->getMessage()}";
                    $error = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $resultJson->setData([
        'messages' => $messages,
        'error' => $error
    ]);
  }

}
```

I hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

How to add this to product grid?
There is no element like ..._columns_editor

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/205741)